# How to use parts of expression as variables in Minimize (NMinimize )?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to solve some optimization problem involving matrices.
A toy example related to the problem looks as follows

```
Ma = Table[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], {q1, 1, 10}, {q2, 1, 10}];
Minimize[{Norm[Part[Ma, 1;;10-d1, 1;;10-d2]-Part[Ma,d1+1;;10, d2 + 1 ;; 10], 2]^2/(10-d1)/(10-d2),And[1 <= d1, d1 <= 5, d2 >= 1, d2 <= 5],Element[ Alternatives[d2,  d1], Integers]}, {d1, d2}]
```

`Minimize` does not recognize `10-d1`, `10-d2` as a valid Span specification, though returns the valid solution. Obviously, this problem can be solved without use of `Minimize`, but for certain reasons it is more convenient to use `Minimize` or `NMinimize`

Answer (score 5):

This is just an evaluation order problem as the `d1,d2` are treated as symbolic. You can force `d1,d2` to be integers using a pattern test:

```
(* you don't need the table here either *)
Ma = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], {10, 10}];

getMa1[d1_?IntegerQ, d2_?IntegerQ] := Part[Ma, 1 ;; 10 - d1, 1 ;; 10 - d2]
getMa2[d1_?IntegerQ, d2_?IntegerQ] := Part[Ma, d1 + 1 ;; 10, d2 + 1 ;; 10]
Minimize[{Norm[getMa1[d1, d2] - getMa2[d1, d2], 2]^2/(10 - d1)/(10 - d2),
  And[1 <= d1, d1 <= 5, d2 >= 1, d2 <= 5], 
  Element[Alternatives[d2, d1], Integers]}, {d1, d2}]
```

Comment: To save a few bytes you could restrict the `Head` rather than using `PatternTest`, e.g., `getMa1[d1_Integer, d2_Integer]`